# Where to put rigidbody on a car model ?

Tags: unity

I have a GameObject car like this:

- MyCar

  - Body with mesh collider
  - Wheel Left  with wheel collider
  - Wheel Right with wheel collider
  - ...   and so on

Where I have to put rigidbody ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Rigidbody should go at or above the level of all colliders you want to include in the car.

So this:

- Car (has Rigidbody)

  - Body (has MeshCollider for the car's frame)
  - Wheel (has WheelCollider)
  - etc.

Or this

- CarBody (has Rigidbody and MeshCollider for the car's frame)

  - Wheel (has WheelCollider)
  - etc.

Or even this

- Car (has Rigidbody)

  - CarContainer

    - NestedContainer

      - Body (has MeshCollider for the car's frame)
    - FrontWheelsContainer

      - Wheel (has WheelCollider)
    - Rear WheelsContainer

      - Wheel (has WheelCollider)
        -etc.

Are all valid options.

I usually put the Rigidbody at the topmost level of the hierarchy for the object, since only content at or below the Rigidbody's level will move with it according to physics inputs - this keeps everything I think of as related to the same unit/object moving together.